# discord.js Automatic Discord log bot to show every change from a text in ftp which edits automatically when log changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need a discord bot for can online multiplayer server. What I want to do is to send that change in report logs file which is present in FTP to the discord channel whenever there is a change in the server logs. Logfile is in the FTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// The log from your bot.
let log = "ZAK%156.203.237.174%Bilal%205.164.106.26%wallhack";

function formatResult(result) {
  let splitResult = result.split("%");
  return {
    "Reported by": splitResult[0],
    "Reported IP": splitResult[1],
    "Reported Player": splitResult[2],
    "Reported Player IP": splitResult[3],
    "Report": splitResult[4]
  }
}

console.log(formatResult(log));
/*
{
  "Reported by": "ZAK",
  "Reported IP": "156.203.237.174",
  "Reported Player": "Bilal",
  "Reported Player IP": "205.164.106.26",
  "Report": "wallhack"
}
*/
```